# Passing JSON Data to WebApi not modifying the database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I pass data through a j query call, I have a auto-incremented key on the database which is ID, so i created a variable on the script to mimic that.

The method on the webApi is showing a successful request, but the code which runs the database changes isn't getting hit when i run a break point on it.

I don't know if this is Jquery or MVC related so i'm gonna tag both.

Proof that request of the post web api is being hit, https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFELC.jpg

WebApi routes:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute (
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Script:

```
<script >
    var id = 29;
    function populateTab() {

    }

    var addvisible = document.getElementById("btnshowadd");
    $("#addpostform").hide();
    addvisible.onclick = function () { $("#addpostform").show() };
    $("#hideadd").click(function () {

        var postObject = {
            ID: id,
            Title: $("#PostTitle").val(),
            Body: $("#PostBody").val(),
            Image: $("#PostImage").val(),
            DateTime: Date.now()
        };


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(postObject),
            url: "../api/posts",
            contentType: "application/json"

        });
    id++;
});
```

WebApi post:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Post))]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Posts")]
public IHttpActionResult PostPost(Post post)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    db.Posts.Add(post);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = post.ID }, post);
}
```

Comment: have you tried checking your api line by line? does your post paramter have the complete values?

Comment: @Redan yes when the object is passed it is corrected the only obligatory value is the id

Comment: @TahaMouhtij this is a routing issue. If it is not hitting the action then the URL you are posting to is not being matched to the routes configured for the API. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. currently there is not enough information provided.

Comment: @Nkosi how can i  provide information, should i copy pasta the two files? or share my github?

Comment: @TahaMouhtij did you read the link included in my last comment? Start with the web api config routes and the controller. You also want to confirm that the client is calling the correct URL

Comment: @Nkosi talks about how little parts are better and debugging checkers etc... guess i'm gonna add some code parts

Comment: @Nkosi i added the configs, i also tested it via postman with a json object and it was working properly

Comment: @TahaMouhtij, then that means that `"../api/posts"` is not resolving to the correct URL. Put the exact URL used in Postman and see if it works

Comment: i used http://localhost:65023/api/posts and didnt work, i added a link to proof that the request is being hit

Comment: @TahaMouhtij is the jquery code even being called? put an alert in there and see if it comes up when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Nkosi it is being called everything done with jquery is working but the database is not being saved etc. The break point on my webapi is being hit on the post method when i remove the id property

Comment: Is ID readonly on the model? Ok you see the constant back and forth. This is exactly what [mcve] would save. otherwise we're left asking, did you try this, did you try that. Not much else I can do for you with what is presented.

Comment: i added a screenshot showing that the request is going from the ajax to the webapi controller,... all i can do for now is share the github of the project, cause following the minimal ... its going to take pages of the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the following:
do not pass any value for id, let the value be null.

Since you mentioned it is an auto-increment id, the database should handle the ID creation portion.

let me know if it works out.

Also try something like(pseudo code , please dont copy paste),

result  = db.savechanges();

if(result > 1){

//redirect code

}else{

// retry logic or something

}

put a break point at result and see if intellisense give you more information on the error

Comment: Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem i had is the date after following Jeylani's answer i found that the ID should not be specified as it is auto-incremented, and that for the date i needed to use new ***Date().toLocaleString()*** instead of **date.now()**;